geom_smooth and standard deviation
I have seen a nice code here using ggplot and geom_smooth with standard deviation
Is it possible to show standard deviation using geom_smooth in ggplot2?
The plot works fine, thanks, but I would like to extract the standard deviations from the model (geom_smooth part): ymin=after_stat(y-se*sqrt(length(y)) 
Because I use formula = y ~ x + I(x^2) the observed standard deviations are not the same as the model standard deviations.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32318/difference-between-standard-error-and-standard-deviation.   geom_smooth plots the standard error.

You can use ggplot_build() to get values used to build the plot (including ymax and ymin created by after_stat()):
p = mtcars %>%
  ggplot(aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  geom_smooth(size = 2, span = 1, color = "tomato", fill = "tomato",
              aes(ymax = after_stat(y + se * sqrt(length(y))),
                  ymin = after_stat(y - se * sqrt(length(y))))) 

pg <- ggplot_build(p)


EDIT
If you need to calculate the mean or other summary statistics on the generated variables, you can access them in the first element (a data.frame) of the pg$data list with: pg$data[[1]].
e.g.
tapply(pg$data[[1]]$ymin, pg$data[[1]]$fill, mean, na.rm=TRUE) 


Thanks, quite valuable. Is it possible to get summaries out of pg? e.g. mean over all values or e.g. for different x values (mpg = 10, 15, 20)? I tried to use tapply: tapply(pg$y, list(pg$fill), mean, na.rm=TRUE)
Error in split.default(X, group) : first argument must be a vector

@SibylleStöckli, see the edit

Thanks again.  I tried to select a specific x value. It works  for the first selection. After the second selection I got an error.
pg2015$data[[1]]<-pg$data[[1]][pg$data[[1]]$x==10.40000,]
tapply(pg2015$data[[1]]$ymin, pg2015$data[[1]]$fill, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
tomato
4.698911
pg2020$data[[1]]<-pg$data[[1]][pg$data[[1]]$x==30.03291,]
Error: object 'pg2020' not found

Not sure what you are trying to do but you first need to create your pg2015 and pg2020 objects first before you can use these codes. if you just want to extract data corresponding to one x value, you just need pg1 = pg$data[[1]][pg$data[[1]]$x==10.40000,] 

I used now your suggestion. Thanks. For the second extract I get and error logical(), even if x=31.22278 is present in your dataset                   > pg1 = pg$data[[1]][pg$data[[1]]$x==10.40000,]

tapply(pg1$ymin, pg1$fill, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
tomato
4.698911
pg2 = pg$data[[1]][pg$data[[1]]$x==31.22278,]


tapply(pg2$ymin, pg2$fill, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
logical(0)


That's because R only shows 5 digits from floating points values, but your x value has actually more (you can check with print(pg$data[[1]]$x[[71]], digits = 10)). There are several solutions to extract your data by value and with some tolerance (see various methods in this this post), the easiest is probably with dplyr::near(), like so pg2 = pg$data[[1]][which(dplyr::near(pg$data[[1]]$x,31.22278, tol = 1e-5)),].

Now, the tapply does not make much sense since you try to calculate the mean for only one extracted value of ymin (corresponding to one x value)

So valuable answers! A final reflection.  I considered  formula = y ~ x + I(x^2).
In my example, calculating sd()  gives approx 20-25 and varies significantly from the values provided by the ggplot (or ggplot_build(p1): difference ymin/ymax to y is approx 5).
In your case > sd(mpg$cyl) = 1.611534 is comparable to the ggplot.
So my question for confirmation

I suppose using after_stat() I plot the data standard deviation and not the residual standard deviation, correct?
I suppose because I use "formula" the output is not comparable with sd(), correct? I suggest: model standard deviation


The formula se * sqrt(length(y)) in after_stat() calculates the standard deviation of the y variable (cyl in my example) from the standard error of the fit obtained by the geom_smooth function (or can be also obtained with the predict() function), see this disccussion or this one.

This might explain why, in your case with different data/formula, sd() (standard deviation of the data) gives a different value than the running standard deviation calculated from the standard errors of the fit. Hope this helped, I found it interesting to dive in the secrets of se/sd calculations from geom_smooth :). If all this answered your questions and needs, feel free to accept the answer ;)
